# object possibly null (ts18047) even after previous explicit check

Tags: typescript

why am I getting `'event.target.files' is possibly 'null'` on the highlighted line when there the null check on the previous line? i know i can use non-null assertion operator, but like i did in the end as you can see in the code example below, but can someone please explain this behavior?

[image: 'event.target.files' is possibly 'null']

```
const handleOnUpload = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.target.files === null || event.target.files?.length === 0) return;
    if (allowedExtensions.some((extension) => event.target.files![0].type === extension)) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

EDIT: when i store the accessed object to a separate variable, it does not complain one bit:

```
const handleOnUpload = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.target.files === null || event.target.files?.length === 0) return;
    const uploadedImage = event.target.files[0];
    if (allowedExtensions.some((extension) => uploadedFile.type === extension)) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this warning, because you are accessing `event.target.files` in lambda function, basically in some callback. Typescript doesn't know how long this callback will be alive. But it knows that it stores closure with `event` and `event.target.files` is possibly `null`.

Here is synthetic example how similar code can lead to error:

```js
class CallbackHandler { 
  private callback: (() => boolean) | null = null; 
  
  setupCallback(cb: () => boolean) { 
    this.callback = cb; 
  } 
  
  invoke() {
    this.callback?.();
  }
}


const event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> = { target: { files: [{}] } };
const callbackHandler = new CallbackHandler()
const handleOnUpload = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  if (event.target.files === null || event.target.files?.length === 0) return;
  callbackHandler.setupCallback((extension) => event.target.files[0].type === extension));
}

// we setup our callback 
handleOnUpload(event);
// now change event
event.target.files = null;
// now invoke callback and we get error
callbackHandler.invoke();
```

Comment: makes sense, thanks. here's one more: `step[key] !== undefined && step[key].length > 0` produces "Object is possibly 'undefined'" for the second `step[key]`; again - helps if i store it to a separate variable